# Xcode: how to set a break point inside one line of code?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

Say I have a piece of code like this:

```
x -= func();
```

Is there any way I can know the result of `func()` without adding a temp variable or inspecting `x`? Also, `func()` is in a binary library so I don't have its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on optimizations, this might not be possible. You could inspect the `eax` register, but that depends on the calling convention and whether the function is inlined. It's possible the return value is discarded completely if not used. Your best bet is using a temporary. In fact, using a temporary would be appropriate for debugging purposes (like in your case), might also be more readable and should not impact performance.